# Java: compile and run hanging at command prompt

Tags: java, environment-variables, memory-management

I'm having an issue that I'm hoping someone can help with. I'm working on netbook running WinXP Pro SP3, 1.6GHz & 1GB of RAM. I've got a relatively simple java program that I'm able to successfully compile and run on other computers (both XP and Win7), so I suspect my code is working fine--I've verified that all computers are running the same version of Java (build 1.7.0_02-b13).

For about the past week, I get maybe three or four compiles and runs at the command prompt (running CMD from within WinXp) before I hang with a blinking cursor after keying my command and pressing enter. If I shut down the command prompt window and restart it, I can compile and run the program just fine--again, pointing to an OS/environment issue rather than code.

The only system change I've made in the past week is to uninstall a Lexmark printer that I ditched a year ago, and removing/reinstalling Java. Oh, and an automatic Windows update... :\ I've used this netbook successfully for programming classes for the past year and a half.

Anyone familiar with this issue and know of some system tweaks to solve it? I suspect that memory may not be getting cleaned up when the java program quits...only when CMD closes, but don't know any tools to troubleshoot. Ideas?

Comment: Never seen or experienced that before, this is very strange. Are you using a script to compile and/or run your code? If so, could we see it? (Maybe the actual commands you run too.)  Does your program manipulate stdin/stdout in interesting ways?

Comment: @Mat: no scripts...just `javac JavaProgram.java` and `java JavaProgram` at the command prompt. I'm importing `javax.swing.*` and my class `extends` another...but it's a class project, so it's not terribly complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was never able to find an answer to this question, the problem stopped happening as soon as I was finished testing the particular program, which runs fine in the production environment. When I originally submitted the question, I didn't think to run some other programs to see if it was something with that particular one...but it appears that it was.

I'm chalking this one up to sunspot activity. :)